# No sound under IPv6 issue of iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, sinch

I have an app that makes users talk each other with `Sinch` SDK(app to app),Sevaral days ago, the app was rejected by `AppStore` because of no sound under `IPv6` environment, following is what they said:

> Performance - 2.1 We still found that there is no sound during the
>   call.  Next Steps Please run your app on a device while connected to
>   an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify any issues,
>   then revise and resubmit your app for review.

But I tested it works fine under `ipv4` and `ipv6`(shared wifi with NAT64 on mac) environments, and I can't reproduce the no sound issue.
I didn't use other api from other servers.

Did anyone has the same issue? 
Does Sinch support IPv6? (I read it supported after iOS SDK 3.9.8)

> This is my testing environment:
>
> iOS:10.2
>
> Device: iPhone6s
>
> Sinch SDK: 3.9.8

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to iOS 3.10 and it should all be good